# When did they begin constructing this fleet?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *Star Wars Episode IX: Rise of Skywalker* we see that the villains have constructed a huge Final Order fleet. This surely would have taken quite a bit of time to build. When did construction begin? I'm guessing it would have been shortly after RotJ, but I'd like to know for sure.

Answer (score 27):

The [*Rise of Skywalker: Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary) suggests that they started building the fleet shortly after the Emperor fell to his

> slight injury

They built the fleet while they were waiting for the return of the Sith.

> **EXEGOL**
>
> The darkness at the heart of the Galactic Empire was unknown to most galactic citizens. Though its extreme militarization and authoritarian rule seemed to stem from a desire for security, they were actually fueled by a dark agenda over a thousand years old. The Sith, an ancient offshoot of the Jedi Order that had, in times past, ruled the galaxy, were once more ascendant. Sith Lords occupied positions of power until the Empire's defeat at the Battle of Endor. Secreted in the depths of the Unknown Regions, however, was the planet Exegol, a Sith redoubt. There, **loyalists longing for the return of the Sith kept the flames of their sinister worship burning as they waited, building a force on Exegol that would not emerge for a generation.**

Comment: `"The Sith, an ancient offshoot of the Jedi Order"`... the *what* now? Is this a new piece of lore, a retcon of Legends or something that was always true? I don't remember ever reading anything about the Sith being an offshoot of the Jedi Order.

Comment: @AndresF. - Nah. It's been canon for years; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hundred-Year_Darkness. Before that it was mentioned repeatedly in the EU

Comment: Wow. How did I miss this? I seem to remember some convoluted backstory of the Sith being originally some dark side aliens who were then taken over by dark side users who took the title of Sith from then and... all these pointless details are giving me a headache :P

Comment: @Andres, I've heard the story you're talking about, just recently.  Might have been in the last season of Rebels?

Comment: @AndresF. In legends the Sith were a race of powerful force users on Korriban, and the name of the evil "sect" derived from that.

Comment: Man, it would've been neat if any of this had made it into the movie.

Comment: @Liesmith - You're missing the point of 360° marketing. The films leave intentional holes that are filled by buying the books. And those books leave holes that are filled by buying ever more niche books about the Star Wars universe, each with their own nuggets of canon info waiting to be discovered.

Comment: @Valorum That sounds awful.  I move to initiate a vote of No Confidence.

Comment: @Liesmith - If you want them to stop, you'll need $5bn in cash. Then you can do whatever you like